# File rotation by chunks in FS2

Tags: scala, scala-cats, fs2

I have a stream of chunks of String. Now I want to write these chunks to files. In every file I want to write N chunks. 
I wrote the following code which solves the problem. But my approach is surely not idiomatic.

```
object Diff extends App{

  implicit val cs: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(ExecutionContext.global)

  val l: Stream[Pure, (Chunk[String], Int)] =
    Stream("Jakob", "Leo", "Tom", "Anton", "Lavinia", "Daniel")
      .intersperse("\r\n")
    .chunkN(4)
    .zip(Stream(1,2,3,4))


    val writeJob: Stream[Pure, ExitCode] = l.map {
      case (ch, i) =>
        val path = Paths.get(s"file_$i")
        Stream.resource(Blocker[IO]).flatMap { blocker =>
        Stream.chunk(ch)
          .covary[IO]
          .through(text.utf8Encode)
          .through(file.writeAll(path, blocker))
    }.compile.drain.as(ExitCode.Success).unsafeRunSync()
  }

  writeJob.compile.drain.as(ExitCode.Success)
}
```

1) So I call `unsafeRunSync()` more than once which is a flaw (since map gets called many times). But I don't know how to solve it in another way. I am new to FS2 and Cats-Effects.

2) Also, I am calling `chunkN(4)` here. Which in my example looks harmless. But in my actually use case, I would use `chunkN(10 ^ 6)`. Am I understanding `Chunks` from the documentation correctly that FS2 would accumulate the 10^6 chunk in memory and would then send them downstream?

I know there is a fileRotate function which works und Bytes as a `limit` But I think it doesn't really help in my use case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, this question is almost a year and a half old, but I hope this may still be useful.

> Am I understanding Chunks from the documentation correctly that FS2 would accumulate the 10^6 chunk in memory and would then send them downstream?

Yes.

To recall a few FS2 concepts: a `Stream[F, O]` is a lazily generated `F` effect (program-like) that produces many elements of type `O`. Now, these elements are produced not "one-by-one", but rather in small arrays of elements called chunks.

- A stream is strict at the *intra-chunk* level, in the sense that each chunk is successfully generated as a whole, or the stream fails. This means that to access the first element, the entire first chunk must be allocated in memory.
- On the other hand, a stream is lazy at the inter-chunk level, meaning that the compilation of a stream would only allocate as many chunks as the "consumer" of the stream needs, at a given time, but other chunks down the line would not be yet loaded and thus not yet in memory.

The `chunkN` method is used to change the "chunk structure" of a stream, so one can either concatenate small chunks into larger chunks, or partition too large chunks into smaller ones. In the example, a call to `str.chunkN(1_000_000)` would return that a stream that, upon compiled, would pull from the `str` stream as many chunks as it needs until it gets a million elements out of it, and then emit those one million elements in a single lump chunk.